# VB.net add DataTable rows to DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview

I've tried to find a solution to this, but can't seem to find anything that quite matches my goal here. The answers I've found are either C# or are wanting the data to go from the DGV to the DT.

I have a datatable, which is built out using an SQL query. In this data table, I have a column "Lab ID" that I want to use as a search index. On my front end, there is a requirement for the Lab ID to be supplied. When the Lab ID is entered, the data table should be searched, and the resulting row (entire row) should be added to the datagridview. Each scan should add a row and not overwrite. I have specified the DGV columns at form load but would like it to grab the column names from the table if possible.

Here is my current front end - noting that the left datagridview is only temporary to confirm the data is coming out of SQL and references the same datatable I am wanting to use for the right DGV. The user will pick the dates, enter the Lab ID, then click Check. If the Lab ID checks out, it should be added.

[image: frontend screenshot]

The other thing I'll need to able to do is compare the results in the data table with what is in that datagridview - if an item in the table is missing in the datagridview, I need to be able to retrieve the missing Lab IDs (don't need the whole row for this one) and add those missing Lab IDs to a messagebox.

I don't have any code at this point because I've not found anything that works, with the exception of this:

`dgScanned.Rows.Add(GetResults.Rows)`

Which results in the string 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' being added to the 'Request ID' column.

Comment: *"The answers I've found are either C#..."*. Then you have your solution. The syntax may be different in VB but the principles are exactly the same so any C# solution can be quite easily translated to VB. In fact, the two are so similar in simple cases that the translation may be little more than removing a few semicolons.

Comment: You're approaching this the wrong way anyway. This should be all about the `DataTables` and not the grids. You can populate one `DataTable` from the database and then create a copy with the same schema, then bind each table to a grid via a `BindingSource`. You can search the first table by setting the `Filter` of the corresponding `BindingSource`. If there's an item, you can get the `DataRow` and then call `ImportRow` on the second `DataTable` to add it.

Comment: I think you've got this a little backwards.  All too common mistake people make is it's all about the UI.  Get your data in the correct format using collection objects (Such as DataTables) and bind that to the grid.  Do all you're filtering, adding new records etc to the data source, then your grid just plain works with almost no extra customisations.

Comment: Alright so based on you've both told me here I went back and so now I have the following. The only thing I have left to resolve is where to place the data table - because each time a Lab ID is entered I need a new row to be added to the datatable without overwriting anything. I've added the following code to the existing function ````        Return dtResults

        For Each dr As DataRow In dtResults.Rows
            dtScanned.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        Return dtScanned````